# JAXB schemagen when you can't annotate?

Tags: java, jaxb, schemagen

Schemagen doesn't appear to create elements in the xsd unless you've got the `@XmlElement` annotation (or similar, like `XmlAttribute`). I need schemagen to create xsd information for some POJOs that come from a 3rd party jar, so I can't annotation those.

How do I tell schemagen to spit those 3rd party POJOs out in the xsd? Through some external binding file or mapping adapter?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?